# Javascript events not working with Element.animate()

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I'm trying to add animation to my website using the `Element.animate()` method in Javascript but realized that animation events aren't triggered when the animation is ran.

Here is my code:

```
window.onload = function () {
  let list = document.querySelector(".list");
  let btn = document.querySelector(".btn");

  // animation events
  list.addEventListener('animationstart', () => {
    console.log('start')
  });

  list.addEventListener('animationend', () => {
    console.log('end');
  });


  btn.onclick = () => {
    list.animate([
      // keyframes
      { transform: 'translateY(0px)' },
      { transform: 'translateY(-24px)' }
    ], {
      // timing options
      duration: 1000,
      fill: "forwards"
    });
  }

}
```

In the code above, the animation runs but the animation event is not triggered. Can anyone explain why this is not working or tell me how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not using a CSS animation (triggered by css classes). The animationstart/end (or transitionstart/end) Events are only fired, if an CSS-defined-animation or -transition is used.

Take a look at the example at [`HTMLElement: animationstart event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/animationstart_event#live_example).

Instead of the start/end-events, you can access the [`Animation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Animation)-instance directly :

```js
btn.onclick = () => {
  // animation started
  let animation = list.animate(...);
  animation.onfinish = () => {
    // animation ended
  };
};
```

- [Animation.onfinish](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Animation/onfinish)

Comment: Thank you for your response. It was helpful.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It lead to the MDN documentation for the use of the `finished` property on the `Animation` object. `finished` returns a Promise when the animation is finished. `elem.animate(keyframe, options).finished.then(e => {
e.effect.target.style.transform = 'rotate(180deg)'; });` [link] (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Animation/finished)